# Multiple regression: Strength measure changes by student but is constant over time

Tags: regression, econometrics

Disclaimer: This is the first time I use this forum, so please let me know if my question is not clear or if you need more information.

I have data which looks like this:

[image]

I want to run the regression:

`lm(formula = SCORE ~ STRENGTH, data = mydata)`, in order to find out if higher STRENGTH of the student (NAME) leads to a higher test score.

Note that the STRENGTH score changes by student but is constant over time. I was wondering if this regression setup is valid, or if the fact that I have no time variation is a problem in a time series regression? Would this allow me to test whether or not higher strength explains higher test scores?

Thank you very much for your help and suggestions.

Glenn

Comment: *"Note that the STRENGTH score changes by student but is constant over time"* what does that mean?

Comment: I mean that Max, Jim, and Bob have different scores (0.3, 0.5, 0.8), but that this score stays constant from period 1 to period 11 for the three students. Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Ah, I understand, I missed that you were only looking at three students!

Comment: I should clarify that I misleadingly used 'score' in my reply to you. I was referring to the STRENGTH values.

Comment: I understood what you meant, as will other users who see the question.

Comment: Generally, it's possible to have an independent variable that does not change with time. However, the study design is not clear. What are "period"? And if they are some kind of time, how did you determine Jim will be measured again at 4 and 5? Overall, I think you need very succinctly tell us how the time (both the time for strength score measurement and time of score measurement) is decided. As of now, the least I can say is that if all the Jims here are the same Jim, then your linear model is inadequate because it overlooks personal-level clustering.

Comment: Thank you @Penguin_Knight. So PERIOD is a timestamp observation (dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss), when a student started an exercise. I have many more students than just the three I provided here. The STRENGTH value is determined once for each student and does not change thereafter. For example, a fitness value that is obtained. The observations are runs completed by students, hence JIM might do two runs in a row, for example a morning and evening run. Bob might only do an evening run. I take your clustering point. I could use the felm() function an cluster by NAME.

Answer (score 1):

The code `lm(formula = SCORE ~ STRENGTH, data = mydata)` assumes the data agrees to the following model ($Y=$ score and $X = $ strength)
$$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot x_i+\epsilon_i$$
where the $\epsilon_i$ are independent and $\mathrm{Var}[\epsilon_i] = \sigma^2$.
You would like to test whether $\beta_1 > 0$.

I would say that the assumptions seem unreasonable in your case, since the samples are not independent. I think the least-squares estimates are still unbiased but the variance estimate of $\hat \beta_1$ won't.

I think you could get an understanding of the issue by making the setting more extreme. Say you have 100 samples of Bob's strength and score, and one sample of Jim's strenght and score. If you ignore this fact and perform linear regression the point estimate of $\beta_1$ could be spot on but the variance estimate would be severly underestimated.

I've tried some code and I don't think you will be able to detect a significant difference (or increase)...

```
m <- matrix(c(0.81,0.67,0.98,0.23,0.17,0.38,0.49,0.11,0.73,0.27,0.51,0.3,0.5,0.8,0.5,0.5,0.8,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.3,0.8),ncol=2)
m <- as.data.frame(m)
m <- cbind.data.frame(m,c("M","J","B","J","J","B", "M", "M","J", "M","B"))
colnames(m) <- c("score","strength","name")
m

lm.fit <- lm(score~strength,data=m)
summary(lm.fit) #2 sided test unable to reject the null
```

Comment: Thank you @dietervdf. Would cluster-adjusted SEs help to address the potential within-cluster correlation, i.e. that the observations within each student group are not i.i.d.? Assume the STRENGTH value is determined once for each student and does not change thereafter. For example, a fitness value that is obtained and matched to each student observation. What I really try to answer is if I can have an independent variable (STRENGTH) that differs by student but does not change with time assuming I am able to account for possible independence issues etc.?

Comment: I'm not experienced with this cluster-adjusted SE's, but I've reading through it for the last hour or so. That seems like the way to go. `plm` seems to be  capable `R` package.